# GetListItems /_vti_bin/Lists.asmx

Tags: 2010, list, development, web-services, soap

I need to get a item by a giver url. (SP2010)
I am using the **Lists.asmx web services**. (I can not run code on sharepoint machine).

I tried this:

```
SPWSList.Lists queryListService = new SPWSList.Lists();
queryListService.Credentials = System.Net.CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
queryListService.Url = "http://myServer/_vti_bin/Lists.asmx";

System.Xml.XmlDocument xmlDoc = new System.Xml.XmlDocument();
System.Xml.XmlElement query = xmlDoc.CreateElement("Query");
query.InnerXml = "<Where><Contains><FieldRef Name=\"FileRef\"/><Value Type=\"Url\">"
+ "sites/mysite/file.docx</Value></Contains></Where>";

System.Xml.XmlElement viewFields = xmlDoc.CreateElement("ViewFields");
viewFields.InnerXml = "<FieldRef Name=\"ID\" />";

System.Xml.XmlElement queryOptions = xmlDoc.CreateElement("QueryOptions");
queryOptions.InnerText = "";

System.Xml.XmlNode nodeListItems = queryListService.GetListItems(string.Empty, string.Empty, query, viewFields, "10", queryOptions,null);
```

And I am getting the error:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException

I just have the url of the item (not the list id, view id and web id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you haven't passed the list name to the method `GetListItems`

You should use following syntax

```
GetListItems(listName, null, query, viewFields, null, queryOptions, null);
```

For more information - http://ojasmaru.blogspot.com/2012/08/sharepoint-2010-get-list-items-using.html